# How to Check if a function was called?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have a parent class `soup` with a method `add` inside of it.  When I use it I want it to add 'x' ingredient.

```
public boolean soup(String ingredient)
{
    if(ingredient is in soupStuff){ //this is just sudocode
        yummySoup[x]=ingredient; //yummySoup is an array
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

I am not sure now how to change this when I inherit it.  I would like to check if I have called to it before, and then do something different if I have.  I don't want to rewrite the function and was wondering if I could check it and then add in something without rewriting it in the inherited class.

Eg.  Check if I added the first `ingredient` if that returns true, I would like to make it so that I not only add `ingredient` but also `aPinchOfSalt`

I know there are imports I can use but I want to find a way without it....
Is this possible?  Thanks

Comment: "I don't want to rewrite the function" - tough luck buddy, that's exactly what you'll have to do...

Comment: I am wondering what *imports* you can use.

Comment: "I know there are imports " ,Please tell us also , So that we can replace our whole code base with only imports .

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can have yummySoup as an ArrayList and while adding into to just check if it already contains that element

```
ArrayList<String> yummySoup = new ArrayList<String>();
if(!yummySoup.contains("<youingredient>")){
    yummySoup.add("<youingredient>");
}
```

This is just an example. You need to use `.contains` appropriately according to your need